# Customize Checkbox without label in jquery.mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I want to customize a checkbox without displaying label adjacent to the checkbox in jquery.mobile. how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>test checkbox</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>

        <style>
        .checkbox-left{   
             position: absolute; 
            left: 10px; 
            top: 28%;
            width: 18px;
            height: 18px;
            background: #d9d9d9;
            border-radius: 3px;  
        }

        .not-checked, .checked {
            background-image: url("http://www.dragan-gaic.info/elements.png");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }

        .not-checked {
            background-position: 18px 0;   
            background-color:#d9d9d9;
        }

        .checked {
            background-position: 0 0;   
            background-color:#6496bc;    
        }

        .hidden-checkbox {
            display: none;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

         <div data-role="page" id="testPage">
         <div class="checkbox-left"><input type="checkbox" name="testCb" id="testCb" class="hidden-checkbox"/></div>
        </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">


            $('#testPage').on('pageshow', function(){
                $('.checkbox-left').off('click').on('click', function(){

                  if($(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked')){

                     $(this).removeClass('checked').addClass('not-checked'); 
                     $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked' , false).checkboxradio("refresh");
                  } else {

                     $(this).removeClass('not-checked').addClass('checked');             
                      $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked' , true).checkboxradio("refresh");
                  }
                }); 
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```